# Why aren't my form session messages being shown? (Jquery?)

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page here: https://github.com/alexwaters/PWTKD-new-CMS/blob/master/taekwondo/schedule-dev.php that is not showing my session messages: `<?php echo output_message($message); ?>`

I have been trying to track down what the heck is wrong with them, but have no idea. They work on other pages but not this one.

Can someone please help me find the noobie mistakes I made?

Per request here is some of the code that may be relevant:

*schedule-dev.php*

```
<?php require_once("../includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<?php $schedules = Schedule::find_all();?>
<?php $messages = Messages::find_by_id(1);?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#contactLink").click(function(){
            if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
                $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
            }else{
                $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
            }
        });

    });

    function closeForm(){
        $("#messageSent").show("slow");
        setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['signupSubmit'])){
    $signup = new Signup();
    $signup->name = $_POST['name'];
    $signup->age = $_POST['email'];
    if($signup->save()) {
        $session->message("We will contact you with details.");
        redirect_to('schedule.php');
    } else {
        $message = join("test", $signup->errors);
    }
}
?>
<?php echo output_message($message); ?>
    <div id="contactFormContainer">
        <div id="contactLink"></div>
        <div id="contactForm">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" />
                <label for="email">Email address *</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" />
                <input id="sendMail" type="submit" name="signupSubmit" onclick="closeForm()" />
                <span id="messageSent"></span>
            </fieldset>     
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Signup.php*

```
<?php
// If it's going to need the database, then it's 
// probably smart to require it before we start.
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');

class Signup extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $table_name="signup";
    protected static $db_fields=array('id', 'name','email');
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public $errors=array();

    public function save() {
        // A new record won't have an id yet.
        if(isset($this->id)) {
            // Really just to update the name
            $this->update();
            return true;
        } else {
            // Make sure there are no errors
            // Can't save if there are pre-existing errors
            if(!empty($this->errors)) { return false; }

            // Make sure the name is not too long for the DB
            if(strlen($this->name) >= 255) {
                $this->errors[] = "Name must be <= 255 characters long.";
                return false;
            }
            if(strlen($this->email) >= 255) {
                $this->errors[] = "Email must be <= 255 characters long.";
                return false;
            }
            if(empty($email)) {
                $this->errors[] = "Please enter an email address";
                return false;
            }
            //Finally add the item to the DB
            if($this->create()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                // 
                $this->errors[] = "Send failed, please contact us";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and some other generic class stuff

*message method from session.php*

```
public function message($msg="") {
  if(!empty($msg)) {
    // then this is "set message"
    // make sure you understand why $this->message=$msg wouldn't work
    $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
  } else {
    // then this is "get message"
        return $this->message;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would post the code here, but it is long. I hope that's not bad etiquette

Comment: Just post the code that you think is *relevant*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I had to use $this-email in the save method
2. I needed to make the form an actual post form
3. The session message wasn't being outputted(?) because it wasn't grabbing the post vars

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to add session_start() to you php file?  Try doing that, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Nope =( the session is already started from one of the includes